# ¿Cómo se dice "brass fastener" en español?

Tags: palabras-raras

Tengo estos *alfileres* ([más fotos](https://www.google.com/search?q=brass+fasteners&safe=active&espv=2&es_sm=94&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=nbAOU6eeK4GwyQHM54GYCA&sqi=2&ved=0CAgQ_AUoAg&biw=1517&bih=725&dpr=0.9)):

[image: foto de "brass fastener"]

En inglés, lo llamamos un "brass fastener", "brad", o "split pin".

¿Cómo se llama en español?

Comment: Podria ser tachuelas por la cabeza en forma circular.

Comment: Aquí en Perú se les conoce como pasador o Chinche de 2 pata

Comment: ENCUADERNADORES

Comment: Si vienes a Chile: _chinche mariposa_.

Comment: Creo que depende de cada país pero en la mayoría de latinoamérica se le conoce como *chinches*.

Answer (score 7):

Los llaman **encuadernadores**. Me acuerdo de que los usábamos en primaria en vez de grapadoras y demás para no hacernos daño

Según el [DRAE](http://dle.rae.es/?w=encuadernador&origen=REDLE), un encuadernador es:

> "Pasador, pinza o chapita de metal que sirve para sujetar varios pliegos u hojas en forma de cuaderno"

Comment: En efecto, es la segunda acepción de la palabra en el DRAE: http://lema.rae.es/drae/?val=encuadernador

Answer (score 3):

`Brass` es una aleación de cobre y zinc que en español se conoce como latón. La traducción literal de su nombre al español sería `sujetador de latón`.

Haciendo una búsqueda en Internet con dicho término, me encontré con su definición, por lo tanto esto me confirma su validez o por lo menos su uso en activo. 
Observa la definición que proponen en éste [link](http://www.arqhys.com/arquitectura/sujetador-laton.html).

La definición que proponen en el enlace anterior es la siguiente:

> Un sujetador de latón o pasador, es un artículo de papelería utilizado
>   para asegurar varias hojas de papel a la vez.

Comment: Es correcto, pero conviene agregar que en español muchas veces se usa (impropiamente) la palabra 'bronce' para significar 'brass' ('latón' es palabra menos usual). Por ejemplo, para instrumentos musicales ('bronces').

Comment: @leonbloy: Sí, en español es más frecuente decir `bronce` que `latón`. Pero en inglés es más frecuente `brass` que `bronze`. Así que en contextos informales, cuando probablemente el material no es ni bronce ni latón sino algún tipo de plástico con pintura brillante, en inglés se suele decir `brass`, y en español se puede traducir como `bronce`. Y por cierto, los instrumentos musicales `brass` en español se suelen llamar `metales` no `bronces`.

Answer (score 1):

Parece que [fastener](http://www.wordreference.com/es/translation.asp?tranword=fastener#articleHead) tiene varias acepciones, pero para los objetos que describes, el término más cercano que yo usaría en España sería "pasador de latón". Aun así, "pasador" tal cual debería de ser correcto.

Answer (score 0):

Al ser usados para papel, en general se puede pedir en una librería un "Gancho de papel" o "Broche de papel".

En Argentina y otros países de latinoamérica se puede usar el anglicismo "clip".

Aclarando que es un gancho de bronce, es posible que lo tengan, aunque está bastante en desuso.

Answer (score 0):

Quiero añadir que, aunque incorrectamente, en entornos de oficinas o estudios de arte en España también se les llama "fastener" sin ningún rubor, aunque lo correcto sea "sujetador" o "pasador", tanto para este modelo simple que pones como para el doble:

[image: fastener]
http://www.papelerialamayor.com/encuadernadores/878-caja-100-fastener-artes.html